# What does rule section ufw-not-local do?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

While using **ufw** for my **Ubuntu 22.04**, I try to understand the **iptables** structure behind it. What concerns me specifically is this snippet taken out of **/etc/ufw/before.rules**:

```
#
# ufw-not-local
#
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local

# if LOCAL, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN

# if MULTICAST, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN

# if BROADCAST, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN

# all other non-local packets are dropped
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
```

My guess is that these "if statements" instruct **ufw** to not mess with packets having their destination addresses as either **LOCAL**, **MULTICAST** or **BROADCAST**, but I'm not sure.

Also, it seems the last two statements are about limiting logging (?) and dropping all other packets not matching previous rules. However, in the file, there is no other mentions of **ufw-logging-deny**.

Does anybody know better what actually is going on here?

Comment: Your interpretation of the iptables rules is correct. Do you not observe a chain named "ufw-logging-deny", i.e. `Chain ufw-logging-deny (N references)`? look at the resulting rule set, not the definitions, do `sudo iptables -xvnL`, as it is likely defined somewhere other than `/etc/ufw/before.rules`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @DougSmythies.

So there is no info about that chain if I `sudo iptables -xvnL`. However, I can find it in **/etc/ufw/user.rules**. For instance, `-I ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j RETURN -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10` or `-A ufw-logging-deny -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] " -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10`.